# Why are my histogram bars all displaying frequencies of 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a series (114 rows) with indexed timestamps and percentages (astype float).

```
testseries.head()
Out[100]: 
Timestamps
2018-04-19 13:23:57-04:00    0.000161238
2018-04-06 13:59:50-04:00     -0.0169348
2018-04-04 11:39:41-04:00      0.0475188
2018-04-03 14:53:37-04:00    -0.00231244
2018-03-29 14:09:57-04:00      0.0209815
Name: Change, dtype: object
```

I'm trying to create a histogram of the distribution of these, as I've done several times before, but am getting an unexpected result when I call

```
testseries.hist()
```

[link to image of output hist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Oj3k.png)

I've tried various options, like setting density=True, changing the number of bins, or plotting in matplotlib vs. pandas, but the result is always a series of thin bars with height equal to the maximum on the y-axis.

What's causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The histogram is correctly showing you that each value appears once. In order to show something smoother, you might want to group counts by quantiles and count, displaying the histogram of the result:

```
testseries.groupby(pd.cut(testseries.astype(float), 10)).sum().hist()
```

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

testseries = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100000))

testseries.groupby(pd.cut(testseries.astype(float), 10)).sum().hist();
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, so obvious! I've used .hist() on df columns before that were floats, and it neatly grouped them. Any idea why it would work sometimes?

Comment: It just depends on the distribution of the floats. There's the possibility that each one appears exactly once, but it doesn't have to be that way.